# Help for literature on entrywise invariant kernels

Tags: gr.group-theory, fourier-analysis, kernels

I am looking for literature on entrywise invariant kernels.
The specific example I have in mind is $K:R^{d}\times R^{d}\to R$ and locally compact groups acting on vector space $R^{d}$.
More precisely I am looking to find properties of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of kernels such that for any elements of the group $g,h\in R^{d\times d}$ I have  $K(gx,hy)=K(x,y)$. Any suggestion? Thanks!
Fabio

Comment: When you refer to spectrum, what space are these kernels acting on? Could you also please be more precise on the conditions you are putting on thee kernel functions (continuity, boundedness, etc)

Comment: One phrase that might be useful to look up: "Toeplitz operator"

Comment: Thanks! I also edited the question to make it more clear.